# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING with Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm getting a response from `Retrofit 2` like:

> {"error":"0","posts":[{"account_id":61,"industry_id":1,"company_id":1,"profession_id":1,"description":"Demo
>   Post 13","tags":"Cinema","created_at":"2016-12-05
>   10:47:41","totalFlags":0,"totalComments":0},{"account_id":65,"industry_id":2,"company_id":13,"profession_id":11,"description":"Demo
>   Post 12","tags":"Cinema","created_at":"2016-12-05
>   10:47:33","totalFlags":0,"totalComments":0},{"account_id":65,"industry_id":2,"company_id":13,"profession_id":11,"description":"Demo
>   Post 11","tags":"Culture","created_at":"2016-12-05
>   10:47:17","totalFlags":0,"totalComments":0}]}

and I have declared two items:

```
public class FeedServiceResponse implements Serializable {

  private String error;
  private FeedServiceResponseItem[] posts;

  // getters/setters omitted
}
```

and

```
public class FeedServiceResponseItem implements Serializable {

  private int account_id;
  private int industry_id;
  private int company_id;
  private int profession_id;
  private String description;
  private String tags;
  private String created_at;
  private String totalFlags;
  private int totalComments;

 // again getters/setters omitted

}
```

but inside `onResponse()` from `Retrofit` when I try to deserialize data like that:

```
FeedServiceResponse feedServiceResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), FeedServiceResponse.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
12-05 17:15:17.318 16724-16724/MY_PACKAGE.mock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: MY_PACKAGE.mock, PID: 16724
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
     at MY_PACKAGE.main.fragments.feed.FeedRepository$1.onResponse(FeedRepository.java:50)
     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) 
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773) 
     at MY_PACKAGE.main.fragments.feed.FeedRepository$1.onResponse(FeedRepository.java:50) 
     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have read other questions/answers on `StackOverflow` but cant seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please explain why the downvote - I have read similar posts and I have tried to create a well explained question. If I'm wrong about my assumptions I'd like to know why and remove the question.

Comment: Your assumption that you are getting json is wrong ... Which makes *I have read other questions* doubtful

Comment: Hmmm ok, that;s an interesting thought - I need to think about it

Comment: You need to implement some inspector and log the http response for debugging purpose ... *Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1* means that your response is string which is not starting by `{` nor `[` which means that it is not a json

Comment: Aha! You were right! I was adding an interceptor in a wrong `OkHttpClient` instance -.- 
Therefore the response was correct from the beginning and I shouldn't have tried using gson **once again** to deserialize

Comment: All is well you just need to remove toString here `response.body().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your server doesn't response with JSON-data. You should check it with some inspection tool or by enabling logging.